# How to use a variable in a IN clause Mysql. Python script

Tags: python, mysql, performance, where-clause, in-clause

I am trying to optimize this block of code to use a single query rather than looping over and over.

```
while not (dataX):
            i += 1
            this_id = '/'.join(this_id.split('/')[0:-i])
            if not this_id:
                break
            else:
                dataX = db.conn[db_read].query("SELECT x AS xX FROM link WHERE _deleted = 0 AND _ref = %s AND _ntype = 'code' LIMIT 1;", data = (this_id,))
```

I want to use the IN clause with a variable that contains all possible substring but I can't get it to work.

```
this_id_list = "'/a/b/c/d/e' , '/a/b/c/d', '/a/b/c', '/a/b', '/a'"
result = db.conn[db_read].query("SELECT x AS xX FROM link WHERE _deleted = 0 AND _ref IN($this_id_list)")
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong and how to fix it? I would really appreciate any input!  This is a Python script btw.

Comment: what does $this_id_list look like?  The IN clause is expecting comma delimited values (and quoted if strings).

Comment: @KevinBott  this_id_list = ['/a/b/c/d/e' , '/a/b/c/d', '/a/b/c', '/a/b', '/a']

Answer (score 1):

```
this_id_list = "'/a/b/c/d/e' , '/a/b/c/d', '/a/b/c', '/a/b', '/a'"
```

This should be a string

Comment: I have tried that and it still didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: What result do you actually get?

Comment: When I run it, result ends up being False